# difficulty in print("ok") whenever I click anywhere in the APP GUI

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2

I used QT Designer to design a GUI, I then imported the .ui file into my python code via :

```
ui_file = QFile(ui_file)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.window = loader.load(ui_file)
        ui_file.close()
```

and everything works fine, the GUI does appear and is functional when I run the python code
However I am facing difficulties in achieving the functionality: "I want to print("ok") whenever I click on any point on the GUI". here is my code:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QCheckBox, QLabel, QPushButton, QFrame, QAction, QDesktopWidget, QTabWidget, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QObject,Qt, QPoint
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyApp(QObject):
    def __init__(self, ui_file, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        ui_file = QFile(ui_file)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.window = loader.load(ui_file)
        ui_file.close()
        self.window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.window.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):    
        print("ok")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyApp('GUI.ui')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

here is the UI file: PS. make a new GUI.ui file and edit it with notepad and add the following code and you will have my GUI.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::NonModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>497</width>
    <height>488</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
   <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Pirates Online Hub</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>Icon.ico</normaloff>Icon.ico</iconset>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="toolButtonStyle">
   <enum>Qt::ToolButtonIconOnly</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="documentMode">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="tabShape">
   <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="dockNestingEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="unifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="setSizeGripEnabled" stdset="0">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="QMainWindow.setSizeGripEnabled" stdset="0">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>501</width>
      <height>491</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QTabBar { qproperty-drawBase: 0; }


QTabWidget::tab-bar
{
    left: px;
    alignment: left;

}

QTabBar::tab
{
    background: transparent;
    color: #757575;
    padding: 15px 5px 15px 5px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}

QTabBar::tab:hover
{
    text-decoration: dunderline;

}

QTabBar::tab:selected
{
    color: #DEF600;
    background: qlineargradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #262626, stop: 1.0 #3D3D3D );
    text-decoration: underline;
}

QTabBar::tab:!selected
{
    color: #DEF600;
    background: qlineargradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #262626, stop: 1.0 #3D3D3D );
}

QTabBar::tab {
    /* expand/overlap to the left and right by 4px */
    margin-left:  1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="tabPosition">
     <enum>QTabWidget::North</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="tabShape">
     <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="elideMode">
     <enum>Qt::ElideNone</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="documentMode">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="tabsClosable">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="movable">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="tabBarAutoHide">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
     <property name="cursor">
      <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
     </property>
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Fairy Coins</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>200</x>
        <y>5</y>
        <width>87</width>
        <height>26</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Slot Spins</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>210</x>
        <y>65</y>
        <width>51</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="editable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>159</x>
        <y>100</y>
        <width>331</width>
        <height>26</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="inputMethodHints">
       <set>Qt::ImhNone</set>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>One Row:       0</string>
      </property>
      <property name="textFormat">
       <enum>Qt::PlainText</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>119</x>
        <y>130</y>
        <width>371</width>
        <height>26</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>        Two Rows:     0</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>156</x>
        <y>160</y>
        <width>331</width>
        <height>26</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Three Rows:   0</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>210</x>
        <y>208</y>
        <width>87</width>
        <height>26</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Stall Price</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>180</x>
        <y>280</y>
        <width>71</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="editable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>140</x>
        <y>58</y>
        <width>81</width>
        <height>31</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>11</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Amount:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_11">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>110</x>
        <y>274</y>
        <width>81</width>
        <height>31</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>11</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Amount:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_12">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>130</x>
        <y>310</y>
        <width>121</width>
        <height>31</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>11</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Price:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>180</x>
        <y>316</y>
        <width>71</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="editable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_5">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>260</x>
        <y>280</y>
        <width>81</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Pieces</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Stacks</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_10">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>260</x>
        <y>316</y>
        <width>81</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Per Piece</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Per Stack</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_21">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>200</x>
        <y>390</y>
        <width>281</width>
        <height>51</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <pointsize>14</pointsize>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Gold: 0</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_16">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>250</x>
        <y>360</y>
        <width>69</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string> Gold (g)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string> Kilo (k)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string> Million (m)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string> Billion (b)</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_31">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>170</x>
        <y>363</y>
        <width>121</width>
        <height>16</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="font">
       <font>
        <family>Open Sans Semibold</family>
        <pointsize>11</pointsize>
        <weight>75</weight>
        <bold>true</bold>
       </font>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Price Unit:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_23">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>270</x>
        <y>64</y>
        <width>61</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="editable">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Pieces</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Stacks</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
     <widget class="Line" name="line">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>-20</x>
        <y>190</y>
        <width>561</width>
        <height>16</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="lineWidth">
       <number>2</number>
      </property>
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="Line" name="line_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>-40</x>
        <y>430</y>
        <width>561</width>
        <height>16</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="lineWidth">
       <number>2</number>
      </property>
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Skills</string>
     </attribute>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>971</width>
      <height>881</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color:qradialgradient(spread:reflect, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.511364, fy:0.506, stop:0 rgba(24, 132, 214, 255), stop:1 rgba(109, 187, 238, 255))</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="Line" name="line_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>-7</y>
      <width>561</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>2</number>
    </property>
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="Line" name="line_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-9</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>20</width>
      <height>1001</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>2</number>
    </property>
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="Line" name="line_5">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>486</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>20</width>
      <height>1001</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>2</number>
    </property>
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>467</x>
      <y>1</y>
      <width>30</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Terminal</family>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background: transparent; color:rgb(49, 49, 49)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>X</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <zorder>label_5</zorder>
   <zorder>tabWidget</zorder>
   <zorder>line_2</zorder>
   <zorder>line_4</zorder>
   <zorder>line_5</zorder>
   <zorder>pushButton_2</zorder>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyApp not a widget so the mousePressEvent does not exist, and less is the window. So in these cases you should use an event filter:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtUiTools

class MyApp(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, ui_file, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        ui_file = QtCore.QFile(ui_file)
        if ui_file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly):
            loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
            self.window = loader.load(ui_file)
            self.window.installEventFilter(self)
            self.window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.window.show()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.window:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                print("ok")
        return super(MyApp, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyApp('GUI.ui')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir!